# What could be the cause of "git pull" resultingin "/bin/sh: 0: Illegal option -r"?

Tags: shell, git

Whenever I try to run `git pull` in a repo I get the error message `/bin/sh: 0: Illegal option -r` and the command fails even when I add the password.

It only affects the `git pull` command. No other git commands are affected. Could it be the results of some hooks or some other such thing? I don't have any hooks installed in my configuration.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: What do you see if you run `strace -fe execve git pull`?

Comment: Whatever does call that `sh -r` expected `sh` to be Bourne or ksh or bash compatible (where `-r` is an option for restricted sh) instead of a standard POSIX sh. Your `sh` is probably `dash`.

Comment: `ls -l /bin/sh` produces `/bin/sh -> dash` which could be the cause. I don't have the same problem on other logins and I may have done some stuff in the git directory in the wrong order. I probably switch my shell to zsh after cloning the repo and that could be a factor.

 I deleted the `.git` directory and pulled again from the origin and the error message has stopped. It is a pity as following your advice would have helped me to learn something new.